# widgets in footer?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

Can i use    **dynamic_sidebar('first-footer-widget-area');** directly in *footer.php*?Any change to made in *functions.php* page? I am using twenty ten theme.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete code that runs this sidebar from `sidebar-footer.php` template:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ) ) : ?>
                <div id="first" class="widget-area">
                    <ul class="xoxo">
                        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'first-footer-widget-area' ); ?>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- #first .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can move this snippet around, but it might break styling. Also Twenty Ten is often upgraded with WordPress and by itself and you will need to create [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for it so your changes stick.

I'd first try to move widgets with CSS or maybe register separate sidebar if something specialized is needed.

Comment: ok.thank you so much.<i>Please help me out for this also..</i>I had uploaded new theme(child theme) in clients server.Theme folder had twentyten and child theme now.But when i  activated the theme in admin side ,the twenty ten shows the corresponding child theme and other one shows the html template of corresponding wordpress theme.Could you suggest what went wrog?

Comment: @treesa I am not sure I understand your issue. Since it's not directly related to moving sidebars around it would make sense to create separate question for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can place that code directly into any file and it will display the sidebar wherever you place it.